# setimagebitmap doesn't display any image

Tags: android

I am trying to display images present in a folder in sd card . the information about the images is read from an xml file. the following code shows no errors but the imageview doesnot display anything its blank . please help me locate the reason .

```
 public class Fadeinlogo_fragment extends Fragment{
    int currentimageindex=0;
    int imageindex =0; 
    Bitmap[] imageidlist; 
    ImageView slidingimage;
    static int fadeinimageindex=0;
    String[] fadeinimagelist;
    String[] fadeinimagepath;
    File fadeinimageFiles; 
    Animation animrotate;
    String[] Imagepath; 
    String Systemroot;
    List<Schedule> FadeInImagePathlist;
    int CurrentLogoImageindex=0;
    Bitmap[] FadeInimageidlist;
    ImageView imgView;

    private void getImagepaths(){

           Systemroot =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            Log.d("sytempath",Systemroot);
          String filePath=Systemroot + "/fadeinimages" + "/fadeinimages.xml";
          ScheduleParser schedulexml=new ScheduleParser();

            FadeInImagePathlist = new ArrayList<Schedule>();
            FadeInImagePathlist= schedulexml.getSchedule(getActivity(), filePath);
            Imagepath=new String[FadeInImagePathlist.size()];
            FadeInimageidlist=new Bitmap[FadeInImagePathlist.size()];

            Log.d("inside get images",Systemroot);
            for(int i=0;i<FadeInImagePathlist.size();i++)
            {

                Imagepath[i] = Systemroot + "/fadeinimages/" + FadeInImagePathlist.get(i).getFileName();
                Log.e("logoimagepath:"+i+" Filename",Imagepath[i]);
                FadeInimageidlist[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Imagepath[i]);

            }

    }
    private void fadeinthread(){

         final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

         final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    SlideShow();

                }
            };

            int delay = 0;
            int period = 15000; 


            Timer timer = new Timer();

            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {

                 mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);

            }

            }, delay, period);


}






private void SlideShow()
       {

        animrotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.slide_in);
        imgView.setImageBitmap(FadeInimageidlist[fadeinimageindex]);

        fadeinimageindex++;
        if(fadeinimageindex==FadeInimageidlist.length)
            fadeinimageindex=0;
        imgView.startAnimation(animrotate);

       }







 @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView= inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.fadeinlogo_fragment, container, false);
    imgView = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fadeinlogoimageView);     

     DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
     getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
     int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
     int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width/5,height/5);
     params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
     params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
     imgView.setLayoutParams(params);

     getImagepaths();
     fadeinthread();

    return rootView;}}
```